# Save spreadsheet in a Specific Folder of GDrive

Tags: google-ads-api

I need help with this Google AdWords script: https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/docs/solutions/keyword-performance. 
Every time I run this script in Google AdWords account (for my PPC campaign), it creates report (spreadsheet) and save it on my google drive. 
I would like to save spreadsheet file to specific subfolder on my google drive (for example Report/Campaign01). I found the article which describes how to save spreadsheet  to specific folder. But I don't know how edit this script and use it. Article describing this function is here: 
http://www.freeadwordsscripts.com/2014/07/save-file-or-spreadsheet-in-specific.html

Can you help me solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your folder and file names are unique, use can save to a folder this way

```
function myFunction() {
  var folderIterator = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("YOUR_FOLDER_NAME");  
  while ( folderIterator.hasNext() ) {
    var folder = folderIterator.next();
    folder_count++;
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("YOUR_SPREADSHEET_NAME");

    // INSERT YOUR SPREADSHEET LOGIC HERE. 
    // YOU CAN CREATE YOUR SHEET HOWEVER YOU WANT, 
    // SO LONG AS YOU HAVE YOUR ACTIVE SPREADSHEET OBJECT.

    // EITHER WAY, IT WILL SAVE TO YOUR ROOT DIRECTORY.
    // THIS LOGIC MOVES YOUR FILE BY ID FROM ROOT TO YOUR SELECTED FOLDER.

    var files = DriveApp.getRootFolder().getFilesByName("YOUR_SPREADSHEET_NAME");
    while ( files.hasNext() ) {
      var file = files.next();
      if ( spreadsheet.getId() == file.getId() ) {
        Logger.log("Found File! Moving...");
        folder.addFile(file);
        DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(file);
      } else {
        Logger.log("Wrong File, id[%s]" , file.getId());
      }
    }
  }
}
```